# Why does my HTC Android phone's screen switch on and then off again?

Tags: screen

The screens on my HTC Wildfire and Desire will just switch on and then off for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

Some badly developed apps can cause device wakes.

Try uninstalling or freezing suspicious apps.

Check the logs to see what is causing this.